# Which is the best method/algorithm to predict rank in an exam based on historical data?

Tags: statistics, nonlinear-system

I have the 10 year historical data(mark and rank) of all students who took an exam (exam happens once in an year and the patter of the exam is always same(number of questions and marks per question) .

Now I have the mark obtained by a student in the latest edition of the exam, and rank list is not published yet. which is the best method/algorithm to predict the rank?

Comment: Probably "best" is impossible to define, but if you assume a certain amount of uniformity of students and exams over time, you might be able to create something good enough.

Comment: can you describe the steps. doesn't have to be that descriptive and all, just the steps to achieve this.

Comment: Something as simple as an average of the ranks over the years would probably be best given no other information about the exam.

Comment: 10 years is a fairly short span with the exam being only once a year. Is the exam at least always set by the same faculty member? At the school I taught in faculty members would rotate teaching assignments and the difference in results on their exams would be of the sort that in one professors class a 45/100 was an A while in another ones 80/100 was a C.

Comment: No the exam is not always set by the same faculty member. and mark - rank distribution may vary over years.  that is why I am looking for a non linear approach.